# Intersection of 2 sets in presence of a third set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I started a Probability and Statistics course in my university this semester.
The professor started the first lecture by explaining the *intersection* and the *union* notations.

She said that if we have 3 sets (e.g. A, B, and C), and we want to get the intersection of 2 of them (e.g. **A ∩ B**), we should exclude every element that is present in the third set (e.g. C). She Illustrated that by using this [Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W09Ny.png).

After I talked to her to state that the correct intersection is what in this [Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOyj.png), and that her Venn Diagram describes the relation `(A ∩ B - C) not (A ∩ B)`, she claimed that we have not yet studied the **- (difference)** notation so the following rule

> **A ∩ B = A ∩ B ∩ C'**

should be used every time we compute the intersection.
I still see a contradiction between that rule and every other probability/set theory rule though.

Is her claim correct?
If not, Can somebody help me with a proof to convince her with?

P.S. she wants a proof that works in the discrete and continuous worlds.

Comment: you are right, probability theory follows set theory so...Your illustration is good enough I think to "prove" it

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine that anyone believes that $A\cap B=A\cap B-C$ for arbitrary sets $C$.  I think there must have been a miscommuniction.

Comment: Your professor is using a wrong definition of intersection. If the definition is not self contradictory you can not prove that it is wrong. What you can do is showing that you can not do theory with that definition. For example with your professor definition the property $(A \cap B ) \cap D = A  \cap (B \cap D)$ does not holds.            Alternatively you can look for a book with some basic set theory and prove that the definitions do not coincide.

Comment: @lulu she presented that diagram in her lecture and stated directly that it is (A ∩ B), and everybody were debating with her about the correctness of that rule, but she insisted that her diagram is the correct one.

Comment: @FOE I looked in the reference she included in the course references list (Douglas Applied Statistics). It clearly shows the later definition of intersection (in the experts solution on Quizlet manuals). But she told us that some references contain misleading info, so nobody can talk to her with an info by a reference.
I truly do not know what I should do. the whole course is contradictory, and I cannot study it.

Comment: Then it is no longer a math problem but a social one (maybe it is worse).   If your teacher is reasonable then show her that some useful properties of the set theory do not hold under her definition (as I showed you in the comment below) ,be careful, if she is not reasonable she can get angry.  If I were you I would study from the book I would not stop going to clases (probably there will be some problems in the course if they keep using a wrong definition).

Comment: I have a number of clothes.  $A$ is the set of my clothes which are shirts, $B$ the set of my clothes which are blue.  Some of my clothes have buttons while others don't, $C$ the set with buttons.  I can talk about my blue shirts with buttons, I can talk about my blue shirts without buttons.  I could just talk about *my blue shirts* and not mention buttons at all.  $A\cap B$ here is the set of my clothes which are blue shirts.  $A\cap B\cap C$ are my blue shirts with buttons, and $A\cap B\cap C'$ my blue shirts without.  Note that $A\cap B = (A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B\cap C')$

Comment: The punchline, as alluded to already, is that the definition of $A\cap B$ makes absolutely no mention of any other sets.  $A\cap B = \{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\in B\}$.  Your teacher may be confusing "$x$ satisfies properties $P$ and $Q$ (*among possibly others*)" with "$x$ satisfies properties $P$ and $Q$ only and no others."  These are not the same, not to mention the second is ambiguous and difficult to adequately define.

Comment: My guess (for whatever it is worth):  in the context given by the Venn diagram, it is obviously useful to think of disjoint regions.  One needs notation for those and it might be tempting to use a shorthand.  Thus "$A$ and $B$ " might be take as shorthand for "$A$ and $B$ but not $C$", or $A\cap B\cap C^c$.  Similarly $A$ alone might be taken for shorthand for "$A$ only"  or $A\cap B^c\cap C^c$.  To be sure:  the point of shorthand notation is to be efficient *without sacrificing clarity*.  It's no use introducing a shortcut that nobody understands.

Comment: Just for clarification, I mistyped her rule in the question as (A ∩ B = A ∩ B - C'), the one she claimed is (A ∩ B = A ∩ B ∩ C'). But I think you got it already from the diagrams. All your approaches prove both wrong anyways as I understand.

Comment: That reinforces my notion that she is attempting to introduce notation to describe each of the disjoint regions in the diagram.  That's clearly a worthy goal, but it's not a good idea to use standard notation in a non-standard way.  If I refer to "natural numbers which are divisible by both $2$ and $3$" I can't have someone worried that I might have intended to exclude "natural numbers divisible by $5$" or whatever.

Comment: @lulu now I totally got your point. But she does that only with intersection, for example, when she shaded the area of **A'** (A complement), she shaded all the diagram except the whole A circle, which means that **A** is not **A only** by her definition. Also she solved an example with S = {yy, yn, ny, nn}, E1 = {yy, yn, ny}, E2 = {nn}, E3 = phi, E4 = S, E5 = {yn, ny, nn}. Her answer for E1 ∩ E5 was {yn, ny} which follows the general definition of intersection. By her definition it would have been **phi** as **yn** and **ny** exist is E1 and E4. That's why I see everything contradicting.

Comment: As she is not here to clarify her intentions, all I can do is guess, and that's unlikely to clarify things.  It doesn't seem to me that she has thought through a coherent notation scheme and, as I say, it is a very poor idea to use standard notation, like $A\cap B$, to denote something other than what it typically denotes.   I suggest:  ask if she intended something along the lines I proposed.  If so, suggest a modification of the notation which might avoid confusion.  If this fails, you might try to bring in another instructor to opine on the matter.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for your comment, I will try talking to her about the definition whether it's that "x satisfies properties P and Q (among possibly others)" or "x satisfies properties P and Q only and no others." as you mentioned.

Comment: @lulu You are right, I will ask her about her intention of the notation and suggest modification if it's the other way.

Thank you all for your comments they really added to the argument the next time I talk to her.